# cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Trying to migrate the app from support to androidx for android 29. getting an error in the android studio **cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError**. Error not showing any file name or line no.

After exploring possible solutions, I found this issue was related to the Binding adapter.

While migrating the app, a piece of code converted automatically by android studio.

**Old code**

```
android:visibility="@{rating.isExtended.get()?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
```

**New Code**

```
android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(rating.isExtended.get())?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
```

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#java) link and used following snippet.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:goneUnless")
public static void goneUnless(View view, Boolean visible) {
    view.visibility = visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

Now issue resolved.

Answer (score 5):

The error is because of `getValue()` or `get()` present in your `layout xml file`.

[image]

In one of my layout.xml file I had written `mutableLiveDataVariable.getValue()`, which is a wrong practice. When my studio version was 3.5.1, it worked, didn't get any error.

As soon as I update it to 3.5.3. I started getting `cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError`. So I removed `getValue()` and changed my code to
`android:text="@={viewModel.firstName}"`

And it worked.

Please check the below links, where it is reported.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143778134

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144604674